# Probabilistic proof that biased random walk return probabilities decrease exponentially

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $\{ X_n \}_{n\geq0}$ be a biased random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $P(X_{n} = X_{n - 1} + 1) = p$ and $P(X_{n} = X_{n - 1} - 1) = 1 - p$ where $p \notin  \{0, 1/2, 1\}$. The initial condition is $X_{0} = 0$.

> **Fact $(\star)$:** $P(X_n = 0 | X_0 = 0) \leq \beta^n$ where $0 < \beta < 1$.

**Proof 1 of $(\star)$:** We can quickly calculate
$$
S(\lambda) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} P(X_{n} = 0 | X_{0} = 0) \lambda^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4 p(1 - p) \lambda^2}}
$$
with the usual first step analysis. Identifying the series expansion of $(1 - x^2)^{-1/2}$ gives $P(X_n = 0 | X_0 = 0) \leq [\sqrt{4p(1 - p)}]^n$. Since $p \notin  \{0, 1/2, 1\}$, we have $0 < 4p(1 - p) < 1$, so the fact is proved.

**Proof 2 of $(\star)$:** Via Sirling's formula and the Binomial distribution
$$
P(X_{2n} = 0 | X_{0} = 0) = {2n \choose n} p^{n} (1-p)^{2n - n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} p^n (1 - p)^n \leq (4p(1- p))^n
$$
with again proves the fact.

> **Question:** Is there a probabilistic proof of $(\star)$, i.e. one that does not require such explicit computations, but somehow uses the transience assumption (namely, $p \neq 1/2$) directly and some kind of large deviations estimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose WLOG that $\frac{1}{2}\lt p= \frac{1}{2}+\delta$.  You have
$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$
for $n\geq 1$ and $S_0 := 0$
where each $Y_i$ is an iid modified Bernouli taking $+1$ with probability $p$ and $-1$ with probability $1-p$

$S_n'$  is the equivalent sum of actual Bernoulis
(i.e. $S_n' = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_i$ with $\mathbb 1_i = \frac{1}{2}(Y_i +1)$)

$P\big(S_{n} = 0\big)$
$\leq P\big(S_{n}\leq 0\big) $
$=  P\big(S_{n}'  \leq \frac{1}{2}n\big)$
$= P\big(S_{n}'\leq (p-\delta) n\big)$
$= P\big(S_{n}' - E\big[S_n'\big]\leq -\delta n\big)$
$\leq \exp\big(\frac{-2(-\delta n)^2}{n}\big)$
$=\exp\big(-2\delta^2 n\big)$
by the Chernoff Bound

This sort of concentration result about the mean works nicely for any walk on the integers that has positive drift when the generators have an MGF that exists in a satisfactory interval (which is always the case for bounded random variables)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the bound I needed. Just to follow up on your comment, is there an analogous result that would give you the exponential bound for a transient random walk on the integers even if I didn't have i.i.d steps?

Comment: when you ask about a non-iid case... that's quite expansive-- rather like asking about non-elephants.  My comment was geared toward $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ with $Y_i$ iid but not bernoulis per se.  As long as you have independence and MGFs for each r.v. you can apply Chernoff bound, but you may find pathological cases where that is too weak to be helpful when not identically distributed.  If you instead have identical dist but don't have independence, then closely related martingale methods like azuma-hoeffding may help.   Again this thread really is about a walk generated summing iid r.v.s.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your comments